# How to get filtered(with pipe) list?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I have a pipe to filter:

```
@Pipe({
name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: Array<any>, filter: { [key: string]: any }): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => {
        let notMatchingField = Object.keys(filter)
            .find(key => item[key] !== filter[key]);
        return !notMatchingField; // true if matches all fields
    });
}


}
```

and i am filtering my list in anotherpage.html:

`<tr *ngFor="let item of _FilteredList | filter:peopleFilter" >`

in anotherpage.ts i detect peopleFilter's context:

```
this.peopleFilter = { NAME: 'Gülcan' };
```

so i run it,i get all object with names are 'Gülcan' in my table. But i wrote in my another page: `console.log(this._FilteredList)` i see all items in that list. Is there anyway to see only those filtered items?

Comment: It is highly recommended that you do NOT use pipes for filtering and sorting as discussed here: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe Instead, filter in the component class. I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

Answer (score 3):

Filter does not change source array. It produces another array which is then rendered in the template. There's currently no way to get access to it, but on the other hand I don't think it's really necessary. If you need filtered array in your code just put it there and render it in the template instead of original one.

So, what you want is something like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AppFilter} from './filter.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    items: any[] = [];
    filteredItems: any[] = [];
    private _filterId: string;
    get filterId(): string {
        return this._filterId;
    }
    set filterId(val: string) {
        this._filterId = val;
        this.filteredItems = this.filter.transform(this.items, {id: val});
    }
    constructor(private filter: AppFilter) {
        this.items = [
            {
                id: '1',
                text: 'item 1'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                text: 'item 2'
            }
        ];
        this.filterId = '1';
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterId" />
    <div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">{{item.text}}</div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppFilter} from './filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AppFilter
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [AppFilter], // <--- !!! it must be provided by some component or module
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class AppFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, filter: {[key: string]: any}): any {
        if (!value || !filter) {
            return value;
        }
        return value.filter(item => {
            return !Object.keys(filter).find(key => filter[key] && (item[key] !== filter[key]));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for filter. It works for me:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterPipe'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: any[], keys: string[], filter: string) {
        if (!filter || !keys || keys.length <= 0) {
            return data;
        } else {
            return data.filter((elem) => {
                var matched = false;
                for (let key of keys) {
                    matched = matched || elem[key].toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
                    if (matched) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return matched;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of (_FilteredList | filterPipe:peopleFilter)">
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot about HTML. Updated

Comment: before your update there was error now error is gone. but it doesn't filter now